# Find duplicates of exactly two items from Array1 in Array2 using LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq, intersect

Say I've got an

```
Array1 [1,2,3]
```

and a List of arrays `Array2 [3,2,4] Array3 [2,16,5]`
I need to return only those elements of the List which contain exactly two ints from Array1. In this case, Array2 since integers 2 and 3 intersect;
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to combine `Where()` and `Count()`:

```
var matches = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var data = new List<int[]>
{
     new int[] { 3, 2, 4 },
     new int[] { 2, 16, 5 }
};

var result = data.Where(x => x.Count(matches.Contains) == 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

since it's `int[]` you can use the `.Intersect()` directly. For example

```
from a in arrays where a.Intersect(Array1).Count() == 2 select a
//arrays contains Array2 and Array3
```

Comment: What if that List in not a list of arrays but a list of objects each with an array as a field. 

Sorry if this is dumb but...

Comment: `from a in objectsWithArray where a.ArrayProperty.Intesect(...`